Next js Sever doesn't start one stopped stuck on Starting... screen
I am using latest next js version as of 09 September 2024 and using LTS supported node version 18 so when I start my server using npm run dev it works fine but if i were to stop it mid way and then try to restart it again it doesn't stuck on the starting... screen


workaround i found: Delete the .next folder and re-build again and again as you stop the server.


I tried deleting the node_modules folder, and it started working fine, but now, once again, when I shut down the server and restarted it, it stuck in the same place.

This helped me (Temporary Solution): I have read somewhere that it may be causing due to syncing of your files in cloud storage so I pause my google drive syncing and since then experience no problem.
